# BottomNavigatorView Displaying Weirdly?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a bottom navigation bar but there's something weird going on that I haven't seen in any tutorials. The menu should have 5 items and 5 icons, but for some reason it only shows 4 of them in the layout and instead of taking the entire bottom by width:match_parent, it is extremely small. I've been fidgeting with this for a couple hours and have no clue what's wrong.

[image: Design View]

Here is the code for the menu

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_home"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/menu_home"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_profile"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/menu_profile"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile_icon"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_post"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/menu_post"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/post_icon"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_notifications"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/menu_notifications"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/notifications_icon"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="withText"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
        />

</menu>
```

and here's the xml with the BottomNavigationView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        design:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_items" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Is this only design preview issue or does this happen when you run the app as well? What version of Android Studio and support libs are you using?

Comment: Run the app...in phone

Comment: Well.. that was idiotic of me not to try... It works, thanks.

Comment: @CheeseBites Please file a bug with Android Studio here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list